# swift_initClassMetadataImpl EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: swift, crash, runtime, beta

I recently updated to the Xcode 11 beta, and my code seems to crash at a Swift runtime function `swift_initClassMetadataImpl` with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Is there a temporary workaround for this?

**Edit:** This issue is still present on Xcode 11.2.1 GM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to do this, works for me (checked in 11.2 GM)

```
Temporary workaround that fixes it:

-Go to Project Target/Build Settings
-"Dead Code Stripping" to NO
```

found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/2099#issuecomment-548978168

and here https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11564

or you can get the previous version here

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

and yes, the issue exists in `11.2` GM

Comment: I can confirm that this does indeed work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Still facing this issue in 11.2.1 @VatsalManot

Comment: @SouravChandra which version of Xcode are you using now? 11.4 _should_ have fixed this, though you never know.